# Javascript check to see if required data is filled out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code. This code works awesome, how ever the only thing I am having problems with is that i dont know how to check to see if the required field is filled out.

I have tried to add the required field option but it doesn't work. Im assuming this is because the JavaScript code is not checking rather or not the "required" data is  is filled out before allowing it to go to the next page....?

How would I go about adding a check for required data and possibly disabling the next button untill the required data is filled out?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#prev").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".page.active").index() > 0)
      $(".page.active").removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
  });
  $("#next").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".page.active").index() < $(".page").length - 1)
      $(".page.active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.inner {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 700px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="font-weight:bold">1.How long have you been working in field of Programming?</div>
<label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
<input name="textfield1" type="text" required="required" id="textfield1">
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div style="font-weight:bold">2.Second Question?</div>
  <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
  <input name="textfield2" type="text" required="required" id="textfield2">
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div style="font-weight:bold">3.Another Question?</div>
  <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
  <input name="textfield3" type="text" required="required" id="textfield3">
</div>

<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Wrap the inputs in a `form` and make the button of type `submit`

Comment: @mparnisari not working take a look at this screen recording i did.  https://youtu.be/Ye_JtD9WSiE

Answer (score 0):

To get the html form attributes/elements benefit you need to wrap it inside `<form>` tag
Here is a demo link, hope this is what you are looking for [Demolink](http://codepen.io/saorabhkr/pen/KgJrKr)

You html would be

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#prev").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".page.active").index() > 0)
      $(".page.active").removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
  });
  $("#next").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".page.active").index() < $(".page").length - 1)
      $(".page.active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.inner {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 700px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-weight:bold">1.How long have you been working in field of Programming?</div>
<form action="" method="">
<label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
<input name="textfield1" type="text" required="required" id="textfield1">
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div style="font-weight:bold">2.Second Question?</div>
  <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
  <input name="textfield2" type="text" required="required" id="textfield2">
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div style="font-weight:bold">3.Another Question?</div>
  <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
  <input name="textfield3" type="text" required="required" id="textfield3">
</div>

<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>

</form>
```

Comment: not working take a look at this screen recording i did.  https://youtu.be/Ye_JtD9WSiE

Answer (score 0):

try this. just write only **required** instead of **required="required"**

```html
<form name="frm" >
  
  <div style="font-weight:bold">1.How long have you been working in field of Programming?</div>
<label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
<input name="textfield1" type="text" id="textfield1" required>
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div style="font-weight:bold">2.Second Question?</div>
  <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
  <input name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield2" required>
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div style="font-weight:bold">3.Another Question?</div>
  <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
  <input name="textfield3" type="text" id="textfield3" required>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
  
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/w3rj9ehx/) of your example.

```js
 

   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#prev").on("click", function() {
        if ($(".page.active").index() > 0)
          $(".page.active").removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
      });
      $("#next").on("click", function() {
        if ($(".page.active").index() < $(".page").length - 1)
          $(".page.active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
      });
});
```

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.inner {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 700px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<div>
<div style="font-weight:bold">1.How long have you been working in field of Programming?</div>
<label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
<input name="textfield1" type="text" required="required" id="textfield1">
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div style="font-weight:bold">2.Second Question?</div>
  <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
  <input name="textfield2" type="text" required="required" id="textfield2">
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div style="font-weight:bold">3.Another Question?</div>
  <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
  <input name="textfield3" type="text" required="required" id="textfield3">
</div>

<button id="prev" type="submit">Prev</button>
<button id="next" type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

Comment: not working take a look at this screen recording i did.  https://youtu.be/Ye_JtD9WSiE